# Array structure in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Can I create an array like this in java???

```
Array
([0]
    array
    [items1] = "one"
    [items2] = "two"
    [items3] = "three")
([1]
    array
    [items1] = "one###"
    [items2] = "two###"
    [items3] = "three#")
```

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this by creating an array of arrays. For example:

```
String[][] twoDimensionalPrimitiveArray = {
    {"one", "two", "three"},
    {"one###", "two###", "three###"}
};
```

You can also do this with the collection types:

```
List<List<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
listOfLists.add(createList("one", "two", "three"));
listOfLists.add(createList("one###", "two###", "three###"));

// ...

private static List<String> createList(String... values) {
  List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String value : values) {
    result.add(value);
  }
  return result;
}
```

**Edit**
@immibis has rightly pointed out in the comments that `createList()` can be written more simply as `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(values))`.

Comment: A shorter version of `createList`: {return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(value));}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define an array of arrays:

```
    String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[2][]; // declare and initialize array of arrays
    arrayOfArrays[0] = new String[3]; // initialize first array
    arrayOfArrays[1] = new String[3]; // initialize second array

    // fill arrays
    arrayOfArrays[0][0] = "one";
    arrayOfArrays[0][1] = "two";
    arrayOfArrays[0][2] = "three";
    arrayOfArrays[1][0] = "one###";
    arrayOfArrays[1][1] = "two###";
    arrayOfArrays[1][2] = "three#";
```

And to test it (*print values*):

```
    for (String[] array : arrayOfArrays) {
        for (String s : array) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For two dimension arrays in Java you can create them as follows:

```
// Example 1:
String array[][] = {"one", "two", "three"},{"one###", "two###", "three###"}};
```

Alternatively you can define the array and then fill in each element but that is more tedious, however that may suit your needs more.

```
// Example 2:
String array[][] = new String[2][3];
array[0][0] = "one";
array[0][1] = "two";
array[0][2] = "three";
array[1][0] = "one###";
array[1][1] = "two###";
array[1][2] = "three#";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] twoDArray[] = {{"one", "two", "three"}, {"one###", "two###", "three###"}};
```